# How to read http body in Woo

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to write a server with [Woo](https://github.com/fukamachi/woo). I need to handle  HTTP body sent by`:POST` method. However, I don't know how to read the body.

In `env`, there are `:RAW-BODY` and `:CLACK.IO` look like somewhere to read body from. But I have no clue how to read it. No documents in repo and I searched on google and looks like everyone just gives examples of giving a response to client rather than read HTTP body.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I check `FLEXI-STREAMS` package and figure out `VECTOR-INPUT-STREAM` (the type of `:raw-body`) can read by `read-byte`, and `read-sequence`.

So the solution is sort of:

```lisp
(let ((a (make-array 11 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
      (read-sequence a (getf env :raw-body))
      (format t "~a" a))
```

Comment: Yes, I think it is just a stream, so you should be able to read from it with e. g. `read-line` (if it is a character stream) or `read-sequence` (if it is a byte stream), or, if it is some special format, you might have a parser that uses the stream directly.